# Azure Update Manager - email notifications upon successful completion?

Tags: azure, updates, azure-automation, azure-update-management-center

Does anyone have a good step-by-step for creating email alerts with Azure Update Manager? I've tried ot use the 'built in' alert, for example 'Pending Security and critical updates' or 'Patch installation failures' and they don't seem to create properly, or work.

I don't understand the role of 'threshold' here - if I want to create an email to alert on any instance of patch install failure?

[image]

And the preview box looks 'wrong' to me, it's a flat graph with no info in?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand the role of 'threshold' here - if I want to create an email to alert on any instance of patch install failure?

**Threshold** value is a user-defined value that is used to trigger an alert when a metric or falls below a certain value.

For example, Threshold value for CPU usage on a virtual machine. If the CPU usage exceeds the threshold value, an alert will be triggered, and you will be notified via email.

To create an alert for `Pending Security and critical updates` from `Azure Update Manager` , Follow the below steps.

1. Go to **Azure Update Manager > New alert rule (Preview).**

[image]

2. Clik on `Continue to create a new alert rule`
3. Select the Alert Logic as per your requirement.

> ```
> ex: In my case, the threshold value is set at 1. The alert triggers when there are 1 or fewer updates received within a 5-minute period.
> ```

[image]

4. Create an Action Group, if not have any.

[image]

5. Select the notification and choose the notification type.

[image]

6. You will receive an alert whenever 1 update is received within a 5-minute time frame.

[image]

Reference:

[Create Azure Monitor log alert rules - Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-log-alert-rule)